# Jmeter | API 500 internal server error | Back End Server : Azure Appservice

Tags: jmeter

I am getting API 500 internal server error while trying to requests a high number of the load. Some of the threads are only getting 500 internal server error, other threads are working fine.

Is there any way why the API is throwing 500 internal server error.

Could you please tell me Is that server-side issue or Jmeter-side issue.

I am just confused whether it is a jmeter issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your question contains the answer already:

> 500 internal **server** error

If you look at [HTTP Status Code 500](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) description:

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 500 Internal Server Error server error response code indicates that the **server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.**

> This error response is a generic "catch-all" response. Usually, this indicates the server cannot find a better 5xx error code to response. Sometimes, server administrators log error responses like the 500 status code with more details about the request to prevent the error from happening again in the future

So I would say that it's a server-side issue, if you want to get to the bottom of it:

1. Check [health metrics of your website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-monitor)
2. Increase [ramp-up period](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide/) in order to identify how many users can be normally served and what is the "critical" amount when the errors start occurring, you can correlate the following charts:

   - [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) - to visualise users arrival
   - [Response Codes Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseCodesPerSecond/) - to see the HTTP Status codes over time
   - [Response Times Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime/) can also be useful to see whether response time increases as the load increases, this way you will be able to find the [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html)